# View a range of lines from a file in another git branch

Tags: git

I know I can view a file from another branch with `git view`:

```bash
$ git show branch:filename
```

But how can I just see a portion of that file? I was hoping something like this might work to see the contents of `filename` between lines 20 and 30:

```bash
$ git show branch:file.txt -L 20,30
fatal: Non commit branch:file.txt?
```

But it doesn't.

Presumably I could pipe the output of `git show` into a bash command like `head` or `tail`, but maybe there's a built-in way? (I couldn't find anything in `git help show`.)

Comment: Can we safely guess you meant `git show` instead of `git view`?

Comment: You could pull that off with a bash trick: `git show blahblah | head -n 30 | tail -n 10`.... or you could run `git blame` which allows using lines: `git blame -L20,30 branch -- filename`

Comment: @eftshift0: Weird that some git commands allow `-L` and others don't, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know `git view`, but there's `git show` which can print the content of a blob. Once you have text, it is simple to extract only specific lines:

```
git show ref:file | sed -n '20,30p'
```

Comment: Yes, `git view` was my brain typo for `git show`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean `git show` and you are using the default viewer/pager, `less`, you can just

```
git show branch:file.txt
```

and scroll down using the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> bar until you arrive at the desired section.

If you want to go to line 20 specifically, type <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>Shift-G</kbd>.

Type <kbd>q</kbd> to exit the pager.

Comment: I _did_ mean `git show`! Ooops. I think that's because Fugitive (a Vim plugin) calls a similar action "view".